# javaScript Dynamic date not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am using the below script to generate dynamic date.

Below is the code.

**The HTML:**

```
<span id="spanDate"></span>
```

**The Script:**

```
var months = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07',
        '08','09','10','11','12'];       
        var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now());     
        document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = ('00' + tomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + "/" + tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

**[Fiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/n4e87x6k/3/)**

It is working fine on all the browsers, but the date is not displaying on a standalone IE8. It works while we change the browser mode from IE9/10 to IE8, but somehow it is not working in actual IE8.

Comment: From memory, IE 8 doesn't support *Date.now*, just use *new Date()*, which works everywhere (and does exactly the same thing as the code you have).

Comment: Hi @RobG, thanks for the info. Could you use my example and provide a fiddle withe new Date()?

Comment: Just delete the characters "Date.now()" from your code. That's it.

Comment: oh yes .. Sorry for the silly question .. Yes I did and it works .. Let me just put in my framework and confirm. In the meantime, could you post your  answer so that I can upvote as well as accept? Thanks @RobG

Comment: @RobG - Works perfectly Fine. Thanks a lot. Do let me know once you add the answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Date.now() doesn't work on IE-8! I think thats the problem.